# MVC Views - Can't access variable passed from controller to View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel

I've been seeing examples like the 3rd code block [**in this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6937186/2171490) whereas the ViewModel's members are being accessed via `model.Member`, however I have NEVER been able to use the lowercase `model` in any of my views.

I understand how to use the `@model` directive and the `Model` property in MVC Razor Views. What I do not understand is how `model.ChartItems` is accessible from within the view when I have code that is nearly identical to the example linked in the first line of my question.

I'd be grateful if somebody could clarify the difference between `model.Member` and `Model.Member` in MVC Razor views. It seems that I need to figure out how to access `model.Member` as shown in the link at the top of this question, but I can't seem to find any elaboration on the matter.

Here is the code for the view from which I'm trying to access `model`:

```
@model Models.StudentHistoryModel

<h2>Student History</h2>

@Html.RenderPartial("_Course", model.CourseCompletion);
@Html.RenderPartial("_Track", model.TrackCompletion);
@Html.RenderPartial("_Certification", model.CertificationCompletion);
```

Here is the Controller action that passes the data to the View:

```
public ActionResult History(int id)
{
    var history = new StudentHistoryModel();

    history.CourseCompletion = db.CourseCompletions
        .Where(c => c.StudentID == id)
        .ToList();

    history.TrackCompletion = db.TrackCompletions
        .Where(c => c.StudentID == id)
        .ToList();

    history.CertificationCompletion = db.CertificationCompletions
        .Where(c => c.StudentID == id)
        .ToList();

    return PartialView("_History", history);
}
```

And no, before you ask, the variable `history` is NOT accessible from the View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much frustrating troubleshooting, I decided to try something a little out-of-the-box... I restarted Visual Studio. After that, I was able to access my members like so:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("_Course", Model.CourseCompletion);
```

However, this presented a new problem. I received this error on the whole line:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'
```

I realized that the statement was attempting to return a value, so I wrapped it in curly brackets, like so:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_Course", Model.CourseCompletion);}
```

Voila. Problem solved, data accessible, models working. I am flabbergasted.

Comment: IntelliSense in Views was always a bit squirrely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@model Models.StudentHistoryModel

<h2>Student History</h2>

@Html.RenderPartial("_Course", Model.CourseCompletion);
@Html.RenderPartial("_Track", Model.TrackCompletion);
@Html.RenderPartial("_Certification", Model.CertificationCompletion);
```

Note the use of Model, rather than the non-existent `model` variable name.