# Returning Multiple partial views from single Controller action-error : Repeat View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to update Multiple from an Ajax call. i use this page : [Returning Multiple partial views from single Controller action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937156/returning-multiple-partial-views-from-single-controller-action) but date in repeated !! why ?

my code in view :

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Information", "Classes",
                            new AjaxOptions
                            {
                                HttpMethod = "get"
                            }))
{

        <select id="dropDownDisplay">
            <option>10</option>
            <option>20</option>
            <option>30</option>
        </select>
     <div id="grid">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("_ClassesList", Model); }
    </div>

    <div id="PagingList">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("_PageNumbers", Model.Page);}
    </div>
}
```

my code in controller :

public ActionResult Information()
        {

```
        var page = new Page();
       // Get Info Page...
        var myService = new ClassesService();

        var viewModelClasses= new ViewModelClasses();

        viewModelClasses.Classeses = myService.All();

        viewModelClasses.Page = page;


        return View(viewModelClasses);
    }
```

my View Mode :

```
 public class ViewModelClasses
{
    public IList<Classes> Classeses { get; set; }
    public Page Page { get; set; }
}
```

output When I go to the next page :

[image]