# Refreshing multiple partial views in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Thanks in advance.

I am working on a product filter view similar to some thing like on amazon. where I have refresh multiple views but the data for all the partial view come from single ajax call how to refresh multiple partial view. I can refresh main content area completely but some partial views are not supposed to be refreshed.

Comment: I understand you are new, but in the future please paste some code to help you out. I typed up something for your help, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I broke it down into steps so you can follow/modify and add your partials like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6937186/6085193). First, add 3 Partial Views, they have the same code like below,

```
@model int
<div class="container fluid">
    <h1>PartialDemo@(Model)</h1>
    <h3>The views will all update when you click update button below</h3>
</div>
```

---

DashboardWidgets.cshtml, the code like below, whatever your csthml page is

```
//<div class="row-fluid">
// <div class="col">
<div id="WidgetID_1" class="container">
    @Html.Partial("_PartialWidget1", 1)
</div>
<div id="WidgetID_2" class="container">
    @Html.Partial("_PartialWidget2", 2)
</div>
<div id="WidgetID_3" class="container">
    @Html.Partial("_PartialWidget3", 3)
</div>
<div id="WidgetID_4" class="container">
    @Html.Partial("_PartialWidget3", 4)
</div>
//</div> // the col
//</div> // the row

// lcik below button to update the partials above
// *****  One button will update them all like you wanted
<button type="button" onclick="UpdateMyWidgets()" class="btn btn-primary">Update All Partial View Views</button>

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // this one button will update all your partials/widgets, you can add more partials in this function and just copy paste.
        function UpdateMyWidgets() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("Widget1")",    // whom to call
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "HTML",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#WidgetID_1").html(data);  // tell it which div to append on return
                }
            })
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("Widget2")",
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "HTML",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#WidgetID_2").html(data);
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("Widget3")",
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "HTML",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#WidgetID_3").html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

When click the "`Update All Partial View Views`" button, it will call "Update" method. If success, the return data will replace  div's content

---

Backend action ajax request.

```
// these actions get called from the Update Buttons
public ActionResult Widget1()   
{
     return PartialView("_PartialWidget1", 11);
}
public ActionResult Widget2()
{
     return PartialView("_PartialWidget2", 21);
}
public ActionResult Widget3()
{
     return PartialView("_PartialWidget3", 31);
}
```

Comment: thanks @transformer  that helped

I have one more question, when I press browser back button it does a full page load but the partial views check boxes and radio button selections are not reset. how can avoid that happening

Comment: Hi, what do you mean press back button, you are _leaving the entire page_, so what are resetting! Are trying to only _refresh_ one `partial` then try [this](https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/1132/auto-refresh-partial-view-in-asp-dot-net-mvc). Also if it worked please mark as answer!

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for prompt responses. on the main page I have rendered a partial view that display list of radio buttons  to filter the search result. selected one of those radio button to filter the result. then I have clicked a button which navigates to different page. 
now I click browser back button which does full page reload but the radio button selection still persists. those selections should be reset

Comment: `function goBack()
{
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: '@Url.Action("goBackPartialViewControllerMethod")',
     success: function(data) {
           // data is your view in oncern
          $('#divGoBackParticialView').html(data);
     }
   });
} `      // `<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="goBack()">Go Back View</a>`


 It would be easier to follow if can you please create a new question, and post your code and what you expect, just tag my user name and I will try and help you with it. Its a lot for comments section.